# Prefill google form field with data from the last recorded response in spreadsheet

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a way to prefill a google form field with say, the value at the last response row at cell 3 from its spreadsheet?

I know that unfortunately the onOpen trigger in the form only works when openning for edit, not by simply accessing the form to fill out.

Hope someone can help.

P.S. Navigating to a certain value in code is not a problem, I just wish I could get the last value on oppenning the form for fill out.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to modify the form by retrieving values from Spreadsheet when users input some values to the form. And this is not the situation when users open the form. If my understanding is correct, how about using custom form? In this case, you can use Javascript and you can modify the form when users input values to the form. You can see the information at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs). If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.